# case insensitive cypher query with match clause doesn't work in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jphp

I'm trying to use case insensitive query with pattern match in neo4j 1.9.5 for suggested search in my web application

```
start n=node(*) 
MATCH n-[Lives]->m
WHERE m.City_Name='Belgium' and n.First_Name =~ '(?i)p.*' return n
```

but it gives following error:
Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
[exception] => ClassCastException

how to solve this issue? 
Is it possible in neo4j 2.0?
Is their any option/pattern for doing this kind of stuff?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One of your two properties is an array and not a string.

Also you probably want to lookup the city from an index.

in Neo4j 2.0

```
create index on :City(City_Name);

MATCH n-[Lives]->(m:City)
WHERE m.City_Name='Belgium' and n.First_Name =~ '(?i)p.*' return n
```

with node_auto_index in Neo4j 1.9

configure the auto-index in `neo4j.properties` and add City_Name to the list of indexed fields.
Then use:

```
START m=node:node_auto_index(City_Name="Belgium")
MATCH n-[Lives]->(m)
WHERE n.First_Name =~ '(?i)p.*'
RETURN n
```

Comment: Thanks, tried upgrading to Neo4j 2.0 but problem while accessing data from Neo4j 1.9.5 to Neo4j 2.0 gives following error: Starting Neo4j Server failed: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it case sensitive

```
match (m:person) where m.username=~'.*amruta_rao@gmail.com.*' and m.is_active=True return m
```

and insensitive with

```
match (m:person) where m.username=~'(?i).*amrutA_rao@gmail.com.*' and m.is_active=True return m
```